# Sign activex control using token

Tags: c#, activex, code-signing

Is it possible to sign an ActiveX control using a smart-card(e-token)? I am writing an ActiveX Control in C# to use in IE, and I want to sign it with my token. The token has code signing specified in usage field. Google results didn't help much. From what I found I have to create another certificate file signed with this one. It's trusted but it's out of the hardware and can be copied around.

Comment: _Did you tried anything for this?_ Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Yes it' s possible. Provide what you' ve tried then you' ll get some help.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I can't find anything about how to sign using the token. VS2010 project properties has signing tab that asks for pfx file, which from what I know, like p12, contains the private key(password protected etc.). And from my understanding so does signtool. No means to sign without taking out a private key.